# CodeIgniter: Getting error while inserting an array with Active Records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Trying to insert an array with the help of CodeIgniter Active reacords. Table has just two columns `id(autoincrement pk column)` and `value`.

$data array I am populating from Google Contact API response. Here how I am populating array $data in controller and passing it to model

```
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);//Getting response from Google Contact API.
$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');  //Fetching email addressed from the response
foreach ($result as $title) {
            array_push($gmailContacts, mysql_real_escape_string($title->attributes()->address));
 }
$this->load->model('gmailContacts');
$this->gmailContacts->saveContacts($gmailContacts);
```

**Model Code is**

```
  function saveGmailContacts($data=array()) 
  {
    $this->db->insert('contact_table',$data);
  }
```

**Error is**

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '0' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `importedgmailcontacts` (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`)VALUES ('VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3','VALUE4', 'VALUE5')
```

I am using Codeigniter with XAMPP 1.7.7 which has PHP 5.3.3 and MySql 5.0

Comment: you need to use key value pairs to do this right

Comment: please post the contents of $data. It seems you didn't name the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter assumes when you pass an array like that that you are setting a single row with multiple columns. The array keys are the column names and the values are what goes into the row. You will need to call insert multiple times, once for each row, if you want to use the ActiveRecord class.

You will likely be better off rolling your own query for this one.

Comment: Do you mean running my own query inside a foreach?

Comment: You can either use a foreach and use $this->db->insert() in the loop, or you can write a single SQL query to insert all the rows at once. Another option would be to use a stored procedure, which has performance and security benefits.

Comment: How can I write a single SQL query to insert all the rows at once?

Comment: the documentation is at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html but it can be difficult to figure out when you're new. basically it goes INSERT INTO `table` (`column_name`) VALUES ((row1val), (row2val), (row3val)); You should also read the CodeIgniter database documentation about escaping the values to protect your site from mischief.